# How do I make a desktop icon to launch a program?

Tags: command-line, icons, executable

Have an interesting issue. I am VERY new to Ubuntu and Linux systems. I have only been running linux on my laptop for a couple of months. Here is what I am trying to do - I recently installed google earth and am trying to make a desktop icon for it. With other programs I have installed I have been able to copy the executable file from /usr/share/applications and then paste in the desktop folder. However google earth does not show in that folder and has a different way of loading. I tried copying the file like I did before but it pulls up as a text file. What I would like to do is create a very small executable file that I can put on the desktop to launch google earth. I found the command line for it is :

```
/opt/google/earth/free/google-earth %f
```

Is there a way to write this into a executable file easily? Be aware I am very new and still learning. So be desciptive as possible, please. I am starting to understand the code, but still struggle at times.

One last question, how do I change an icon image? I am not seeing the setting to change it.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to create in your desktop directory (usually `~/Desktop`) a .desktop file, let say `google_earth.desktop` with the following content inside:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Google Earth       
Comment=Open Google Earth
Exec=/opt/google/earth/free/google-earth %f
Icon=google-earth
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Don't forget to make it executable. You can do this from terminal using the following command:

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/google_earth.desktop
```

See also [how to create a .desktop file using a text editor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Using_a_text_editor).

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! Really appreciate the help. Can all .desktop files be opened to change the icon? Or is there another option somewhere to change it? Thanks on the executable though...