# Launching script containing virtual env through desktop icon

Tags: .desktop, virtualenv

I want to launch Spyder with tensorflow environment activated directly through a desktop icon. For this purpose, I created a desktop icon launching a virtualenv and then my application. Many posts already exist but I cannot find a solution for this exact problem. Here is my spyder.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/alexis/tensorflow/bin/activate
spyder3
```

and here is my desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Spyder     
Comment=Spyder
Exec='/home/alexis/Launcher/spyder.sh'
Icon=spyder3
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
Name[en_US]=Spyder
```

The files have `chmod +x`. From a terminal, the script works as expected. From the desktop, the script launches Spyder but the environment is not activated. What I am missing?

Related questions not answering my question: 
[How do I make a desktop icon to launch a program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476981/how-do-i-make-a-desktop-icon-to-launch-a-program)
and 
[How do I automate the activation of Python environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490612/how-do-i-automate-the-activation-of-python-environment)

Answer (score 3):

To run your python script within the virtual environment, you simply have to execute the python binary which is in the bin folder of your virtual env folder.

Ie : if your virtual env within `/home/alexis/myvirtualenv` and if the script you want to execute is named `/home/alexis/scripts/my_python_file.py`, you will have to run your python script this way :

```
/home/alexis/myvirtualenv/bin/python /home/alexis/scripts/my_python_file.py
```

**For your specific needs :**
Try to put the following code within `spyder.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/alexis/tensorflow/bin/python spyder3  # you may have to put the full path to spyder3
```

Comment: The code is working in a terminal (launching Spyder and access to tensorflow), but not through the desktop icon (launching Spyder but not in my virtualenv). I've replaced spyder3 with /usr/bin/spyder3

Comment: When the second line is only "/home/alexis/tensorflow/bin/python3", the problem is similar: OK in a terminal (open python3 in virtualenv), but not through desktop icon (open python3 but not in my virtualenv)

Comment: I have "There was an error launching the application." I tried with ", ' and with nothing. If I let Exec="xterm", it works but it is only an xterm

Comment: i made a mistake. Try `Exec="xterm -e /home/alexis/Launcher/spyder.sh"`

Comment: same error "There was an error launching the application."

Comment: can you provide maybe a screenshot so we can better understand from where the error message is comming from ?

Comment: When clicking on Spyder icon, I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkWvh.png No error when "xterm" or "/home/alexis/Launcher/spyder.sh" alone

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before. The difference lays between an interactive shell and a non-interactive shell. so change `#!/bin/bash` for `#!/bin/bash -i` and it should work ;)